# What does the '&' means in a Unary Operator of a Class?

Tags: c++, class, reference, increment

```
class CDate
{
  // some declarations
  public: 
    CDate& operator ++ ()
    {
      // increment function;     
      return *this; 
    }
};
```

Does the '&' mean a reference that is being a return?

Thanks

SpecC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you answered your own question. `CDate &` simply means that the operator returns a reference to a `CDate` object. It has no special meaning because it's an operator, it means the same in any other function.

Comment: By front or back, do you mean like `CDate& operator` or `CDate &operator`? If so, yes, both are equivalent.

Comment: If, in the other hand, you mean `CDate&` vs. `&CDate` then there is a huge difference, with the first being correct and the later a compile time error.